# Why $F[x]/p(x)$ would contain $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I am reading *Abstract Algebra* by *Hungerford*, and I am really confused about how we can extend a ring to a bigger ring. Here's what I got from the book:

> $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$. Then, $F[x]/p(x)$ contains a subring $F^*$ that is isomorphic to $F$.

I get that part. But, then it goes:

> $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$. Then, $F[x]/p(x)$ is a commutative ring with identiy (OK I see that) containts $F$.

Why contains $F$? We can only know that it would contain something that is isomorphic to $F$, how suddenly that thing becomes $F$? I really need to understand this in order to understand what's going on in the next chapter which discussess about extension field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To make myself more clear, let's consider $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which is a field, and consider polynomial $p(x)=x^3+x+2$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Then how can we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_3\subset\mathbb{Z}_3/p(x)$?

Comment: It's a conceptual abuse to facilitate communication, the author is redefining $F$ as $F^*$.

Comment: @GitGud I made some edit. I guess my confusion was, the elements in $F$ are "constants" while the elements in $F/p(x)$ are congruent classes. It doesn't make sense to me to consider them as the same, although I can see why they are isomorphic.

Comment: *It doesn't make sense to me to consider them as the same* - so, how do you plan on interpreting $F[x]/(p)$ as an extension of $F$? There is a common theme in abstract algebra of **identification**. Better get used to it.

Comment: In algebra, "is [the same as]" often becomes a synonym for "is isomorphic to."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In algebra, we usually study objects (groups, rings, modules, etc.) up to isomorphism. In other words, our theory treats two isomorphic objects as the same, since an isomorphism tells us when two objects look the same *as objects*. For instance, any ring-related theorem about the integers is true for any ring isomorphic to them.  Here we just need to know that there's something ($F^*$) that looks identical (as a field) to $F$ sitting in $F[x]/(p(x))$, so that we can apply our theory about $F$ to that object when we're working in $F[x]/(p(x))$. So in this case, we can just think of $F^*$ as the same object as $F$; we don't really care about the actual symbols that represent $F$.